# How to register single Gmail account in Amazon SES?

Tags: amazon-web-services, gmail, cloud, amazon-ses

I want to use amazon SES for the following use case:

1. Send email to my Gmail
2. Write email to S3 bucket

This seems fairly straightforward and SES docs are helpful.  However, it seems like for receiving email, you need to have a verified domain.  In my case, I'm just using my personal Gmail, so I can't verify the entire gmail.com domain.   Can I still use SES for my personal use case above or does SES only work with company domains?

Answer (score 0):

You need your own domain.

You would create an `MX` record in the domain to point to Amazon SES.

The service is designed for companies that send LOTS of email. It is not designed for personal use.